# jQuery activate same button with multiple divs, same layout

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a toggle feature to swap out the buttons of dynamically generated html. I'd like for the buttons to swap out the deselect and select buttons, but I ran into a problem due to duplicate button names.

Here is the code I have:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#select-image', function() {
    $('#deselect-image').show();
    $('#select-image').hide();
});
$(document).on('click', '#deselect-image', function() {
    $('#select-image').show();
    $('#deselect-image').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="190" class="image-flex">
    <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;"><br>
    <span id="select-toggle">
        <button id="deselect-image" style="display:none;">Deselect</button>
        <button id="select-image">Select</button>
    </span>&nbsp;<button id="remove-image">X</button>
</div>
<div id="191" class="image-flex">
    <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;"><br>
    <span id="select-toggle">
        <button id="deselect-image" style="display:none;">Deselect</button>
        <button id="select-image">Select</button>
    </span>&nbsp;<button id="remove-image">X</button>
</div>      
<div id="192" class="image-flex">
    <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;"><br>
    <span id="select-toggle">
        <button id="deselect-image" style="display:none;">Deselect</button>
        <button id="select-image">Select</button>
    </span>&nbsp;<button id="remove-image">X</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to use a `class` attribute instead of `id` so that you can work with the button elements in a more general way.

In the example below, the `deselect-image` and the `select-image` have been set for use as classes with the buttons. The jQuery handling has been modified so that every button of the same class gets a handler.

Since the buttons are in pairs with the `deselect-button` first, the `prev()` and `next()` functions refer to the opposite button depending upon which one gets clicked.

Try the runnable example below.

```js
$('.deselect-image').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next().show(); // the select-image button
    $(this).hide();
});

$('.select-image').on('click', function() {
    $(this).prev().show(); // the deselect-image button
    $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="190" class="image-flex">
    <img src="uploads/img/AJ/a.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;"><br>
    <span id="select-toggle">
        <button class="deselect-image" style="display:none;">Deselect</button>
        <button class="select-image">Select</button>
    </span>&nbsp;<button id="remove-image">X</button>
</div>
<div id="191" class="image-flex">
    <img src="uploads/img/AJ/b90.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;"><br>
    <span id="select-toggle">
        <button class="deselect-image" style="display:none;">Deselect</button>
        <button class="select-image">Select</button>
    </span>&nbsp;<button id="remove-image">X</button>
</div>      
<div id="192" class="image-flex">
    <img src="uploads/img/AJ/c.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;"><br>
    <span id="select-toggle">
        <button class="deselect-image" style="display:none;">Deselect</button>
        <button class="select-image">Select</button>
    </span>&nbsp;<button id="remove-image">X</button>
</div>
```